# How to use dialogs with dispatch service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, botframework

I cannot use `beginDialog` with the **LUIS** dispatch. I want to use processHomeAutomation function to begin a new dialog but it gives me an error.

> [onTurnError]: Error: DialogContext.beginDialog(): A dialog with an id
>   of 'TOP_LEVEL_DIALOG' wasn't found.

I imported `TOP_LEVEL_DIALOG` but still does not work. It only works with MainDialog which is the name of the current class.

```
const { ConfirmPrompt, DialogSet, DialogTurnStatus, OAuthPrompt, WaterfallDialog } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const { LogoutDialog } = require('./logoutDialog');
const { TopLevelDialog, TOP_LEVEL_DIALOG } = require('./topLevelDialog');
const { LuisRecognizer, QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');

const CONFIRM_PROMPT = 'ConfirmPrompt';
const MAIN_DIALOG = 'MainDialog';
const MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG = 'MainWaterfallDialog';
const OAUTH_PROMPT = 'OAuthPrompt';

let loggedIn = true;

class MainDialog extends LogoutDialog {
    constructor() {
        super(MAIN_DIALOG, process.env.connectionName);

        this.addDialog(new TopLevelDialog());

        this.addDialog(new OAuthPrompt(OAUTH_PROMPT, {
            connectionName: process.env.connectionName,
            text: 'Please Sign In',
            title: 'Sign In',
            timeout: 300000
        }));
        this.addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.promptStep.bind(this),
            this.loginStep.bind(this),
            this.displayTokenPhase1.bind(this),
            this.displayTokenPhase2.bind(this)
        ]));
    }

    /**
     * The run method handles the incoming activity (in the form of a DialogContext) and passes it through the dialog system.
     * If no dialog is active, it will start the default dialog.
     * @param {*} dialogContext
     */
    async run(context, accessor) {

        console.log(this.id)

        if (loggedIn) {

            const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
            dialogSet.add(this);

            const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(context);
            const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();

            const dispatchRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer({
                applicationId: process.env.LuisAppId,
                endpointKey: process.env.LuisAPIKey,
                endpoint: `https://${process.env.LuisAPIHostName}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`
            }, {
                    includeAllIntents: true,
                    includeInstanceData: true
                }, true);

            const qnaMaker = new QnAMaker({
                knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
                endpointKey: process.env.QnAAuthKey,
                host: process.env.QnAEndpointHostName
            });

            this.dispatchRecognizer = dispatchRecognizer;
            this.qnaMaker = qnaMaker;
            const recognizerResult = await dispatchRecognizer.recognize(context);

            // Top intent tell us which cognitive service to use.
            const intent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(recognizerResult);

            // Next, we call the dispatcher with the top intent.
            await this.dispatchToTopIntentAsync(context, intent, recognizerResult, dialogContext, results, dialogSet);

        } else {

            const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
            dialogSet.add(this);

            const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(context);
            const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
            if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
                console.log(this.id)
                await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
            }

        }

    }

    async promptStep(stepContext) {
        return await stepContext.beginDialog(OAUTH_PROMPT);
    }

    async loginStep(stepContext) {
        // Get the token from the previous step. Note that we could also have gotten the
        // token directly from the prompt itself. There is an example of this in the next method.
        const tokenResponse = stepContext.result;
        if (tokenResponse) {
            loggedIn = true;
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity('You are now logged in.');
            return await stepContext.prompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT, 'Would you like to view your token?');
        }
        await stepContext.context.sendActivity('Login was not successful please try again.');
        return await stepContext.endDialog();
    }

    async displayTokenPhase1(stepContext) {
        await stepContext.context.sendActivity('Thank you.');

        const result = stepContext.result;
        if (result) {
            return await stepContext.beginDialog(OAUTH_PROMPT);
        }
        return await stepContext.endDialog();
    }

    async displayTokenPhase2(stepContext) {
        const tokenResponse = stepContext.result;
        if (tokenResponse) {
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity(`Here is your token ${tokenResponse.token}`);
        }
        return await stepContext.endDialog();
    }


    /// QNA STUFF STATS HERE
    async dispatchToTopIntentAsync(context, intent, recognizerResult, dialogContext, results) {
        switch (intent) {
            case 'automation':
                await this.processHomeAutomation(context, recognizerResult.luisResult, dialogContext, results);
                break;
            case 'qna':
                await this.processSampleQnA(context);
                break;
            default:
                this.logger.log(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${intent}.`);
                await context.sendActivity(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${intent}.`);
                break;
        }
    }

    async processHomeAutomation(context, luisResult, dialogContext, results, dialogSet) {
        return await dialogContext.beginDialog(TOP_LEVEL_DIALOG);
    }

    async processSampleQnA(context) {
        this.logger.log('processSampleQnA');

        const results = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);

        if (results.length > 0) {
            await context.sendActivity(`${results[0].answer}`);
        } else {
            await context.sendActivity('Sorry, could not find an answer in the Q and A system.');
        }
    }
}

module.exports.MainDialog = MainDialog;
```

Comment: Can you post the topLevelDialog.js file, as well? So far, your code is working for me, so I am wondering about its construction.

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding it within waterfall. So, firs step check if the user is logged in and if not go to LUIS. Based on intents direct to relevant dialogs and when ended go back to main dialog check if logged in otherwise go to LUIS. Us this a good practice.